# Connect four winner

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to check for a winner vertically and horizontally in Connect 4. I have a playing board of 7,6 when you click the button you change the labels color. The Labels are in a 2 dimensional array. The loop I have created to make it see if there is a winner every time the button is clicked, doesn't work.

```
Dim board(7,6) as integer

Dim Labelboard as (7,6) as label

Labelboard(0,0) = L00 'I have 41 others 

For i as integer = 0 to 3
    For k as integer = 0 to 3
        If pturn =1 then tag= "p1"
            'Horizontal Win
            For i As Integer = 0 To 3
                For k As Integer = 0 To 6
                    If Labelboard(i, k).Tag.ToString = "p1" AndAlso
                      Labelboard(i + 1, k).Tag.ToString = "p1" AndAlso
                      Labelboard(i + 2, k).Tag.ToString = "p1" AndAlso
                      Labelboard(i + 3, k).Tag.ToString = "p1" Then
                        MsgBox("Game Over Player 1 Wins.")
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I looked at the edit history, and yes, it was there twice originally.  So is `For k` - which means the outer loop is only going to execute once.

Comment: A really good way to figure these things out is to out a breakpoint at the first outerloop, hit F5 and then step through the code.  You should quickly see where you're going wrong in the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "doesn't work" is not a useful problem statement.

Comment: Thanks @Tim I'll have to try that. I tried a couple different things every time the loop finds a match it adds on a label, but that didn't go to well. Would you happen to know if my loop is correct or close to correct? I've been looking and trying a bunch of different things for the past two hours.

Comment: @Jason - Are you required to use `For` loops for this, or are you able or open to other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Your current posted code doesn't need the outer `For` loops, and you'll get an index out of bound for `For k As Integer = 0 To 6`, as there's only 6 elements in that dimension - `LabelBoard(7, 6)`.  It should be `For k As Integer = 0 To 5`.

With those changes in mind, the following code (not tested) should do the trick:

```
If pturn = 1 Then tag = "p1"
For i As Integer = 0 To 3
  For k As Integer = 0 To 5
      If LabelBoard(i, k).Tag.ToString() = tag AndAlso
        LabelBoard(i + 1, k).Tag.ToString() = tag AndAlso
        LableBoard(i + 2, k).Tag.ToString() = tag AndAlso
        LabelBoard(i + 3, k).Tag.ToString() = tag Then
            MsgBox("Game Over Player 1 Wins.")
      End If
  Next
Next
```

However, that's a pretty brute force way to do it, and you're not flagging that the game is over, simply displaying a message box.   Another approach would be to use a couple of `While` loops (there are other ways as well).  The advantage of the `While` loop is that once a connect four is found, you can exit the loop (I like efficiency, even though this is still inefficient).

For example, assuming the standard 6 rows, 7 columns, you could do something like this:

```
Dim currentRow As Integer = 0
Dim currentCol As Integer = 0
Dim connectFour As Boolean = False
Dim connectCount As Integer = 0

If pturn = 1 Then tag = "p1"

While Not connectFour And currentRow <= 5
    currentCol = 0
    connectCount = 0
    While Not connectCount = 4 And currentCol <= 6
        If labelBoard(currentCol, currentRow).Tag.ToString() = tag Then
          connectCount = connectCount + 1
        Else
          connectCount = 0
        End If  
        currentCol = currentCol + 1
    End While
    If connectCount = 4 Then 
       connectFour = True
    Else
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
End While
```

The above simply sets four local variables, one for the currentRow, one for the currentColumn, one for the count of connected labels and a flag for whether or not connect four was found.

The outer `While` loop will run as long as `connectFour` is `False` and the `currentRow` is less than or equal to 5.

The inner loop (as we're now looking at a specific row) first resets the current column to 0 and the connect count to 0.

During the inner loop, each column is checked.  If it matches `tag`, then the `connectCount` is incremented by 1.  If it doesn't, then `connectCount` is reset to 0.  `currentCol` is incremented by 1 at the end of each iteration of the inner loop.

When the inner loop is finished (either a connect 4 was found or we've reached the end of the current row) then we check the value of `connectCount`, and if it's 4 then we set `connectFour` to `True`, which will end the outer looop.

Not much different than your original code (modified), except it won't check every row if a connect four is found early on.